# How to fetch multiple Rss Feed

Tags: android

How to fetch multiple Rss feed message in single List view? Is there any idea to parse more than one feed url? I searched in google, but I didn't get any proper answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to parse the feeds seperately (as each feed is a self contained xml) - If you parse each feed, and build a list of items parsed, then once you have read all the items, put them in a single list and sort them.

then you can return that list to your listView and they will be displayed like one continuous feed of data.